# Css3 transition delay

Tags: css-transitions, delay

I am trying to make sequential delay for opacity transition:

```
$('.wrapper').children('div').each(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('hidden').addClass('visible');               
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7HgLK/5/

Now they all fade at once, I would like a sequential fade.

Is it possible with just css?

Comment: There is a property to delay a transition in CSS, but you're triggering the same behaviour for each element in your code. At the very least you will need to be able to give each element a distinct class name, are you able to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

You can use the transition delay property:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-delay.asp

HTML:

```html
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
<div class="third"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.first {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0s;
    -ms-transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
.second {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 1s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 1s;
    -o-transition-delay: 1s;
    -ms-transition-delay: 1s;
    transition-delay: 1s;
}
.third {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 2s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 2s;
    -o-transition-delay: 2s;
    -ms-transition-delay: 2s;
    transition-delay: 2s;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/je9p5/

For it to work on n children you have to use javascript like so:

Javascript:

```
$('.wrapper').children('div').each(function(index, value) {
    .css('-webkit-transition-delay', index + 's')
    .css('-moz-transition-delay', index + 's')
    .css('-ms-transition-delay', index + 's')
    .css('-o-transition-delay', index + 's')
    .css('transition-delay', index + 's');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4x6wC/